# Arc length parametrization (from my exam)

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields, arc-length

[a)][picture of exam question (txt in Serbian)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKHc3.jpg)1]I have 2 long problem, and i must to solve this for exam from calculs 4:

a)How to finde arc length of this function with vector- parametric rep. s(t)=sqrt(t,sqrt(t),e^t), where t is from 1 to 3.
I' stack , i know l=int(√(t'²+(√t')²+(e^2t)'²) from 1 to 3
,but how compute this integral

b) and how to find surface of surface def. with:
{x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2

x^2+y^2=ay}

I try, but...
[b)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqnEk.jpg)

Comment: This is difficult to read and, yes, you get an integral that cannot be evaluated without a calculator or numerical techniques. So?

Comment: I posted picure with exam ( in Serbian leanguge)